# Generic type meaning for java.lang.Enum

Tags: java, generics, enums

What does the generic type mean for the below source code for java.lang.Enum abstract class:

```
public abstract class Enum<E extends Enum<E>>
    implements Comparable<E>, Serializable {
```

I suppose E should extend Enum type since it is abstract but source code says that Enum again should be of `type<E>`.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

Comment: By the way, CRTP is a non-theory-aware name for [F-bounded quantification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification).